# Jekyll include_relative go up one level from pages sub-directory

Tags: html, jekyll, liquid

I'm using Jekyll and have a `src/` folder that contains my `includes` directory inside of here, I've recently added a sub-folder to act to hold additional pages, e.g: https://example.com/services/service but Jekyll doesn't understand how to move up one level to get to my `includes` folder so that I can include common templates such as my header and footer.

What am I missing?

```
.
└── src/
    ├── assets/
    ├── includes/
    │   ├── header.html
    │   └── footer.html
    ├── js/
    ├── scss/ 
    ├── services/
    │   ├── service.html
    │   └── compare.html
    ├── index.html
    ├── about.html
    └── contact.html
```

My `service.html` page has:

```html
{% include_relative ../includes/header.html %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a plugin to get this behaviour github.com/tnhu/jekyll-include-absolute-plugin